# Powershell Bug in copy/move/rename when filename contains [square bracket characters]?

Tags: powershell, filenames

Please pardon a noob question, but I've been completely baffled by this one.

I have a "depositor" directory where user-submitted files arrive, and have no control over the incoming file names.

I created a parser in PS which quite successfully moves files (based on file name content) to an appropriate destination.

This works fine EXCEPT when a filename contains either "[" or "]".

Here is the "rename" pre-processor, which fails to actually rename a file containing either of the pesky bracket characters:

```
 cd $folderpath
 foreach ($i in get-childitem $folderpath) {   
     if ($i.mode.substring(0,1) -ne “d”) {
        $name = $i.name.replace("[","_")
        $name = $name.replace("]","_")
        Write-Host $i -foregroundcolor “blue”       
        Write-Host $name -foregroundcolor “green”  

        Rename-Item $i $name 

     }
 }
```

This also fails for ren, copy, move and their cmdlet equivalents

Any insight you might be able to provide would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance . . .

Comment: work on you escaping-fu: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_PowerShell_1.0_String_Quoting_and_Escape_Sequences

Comment: @aking1012: That works for literals, but not for variables.

Answer (score 18):

Unless you use `-LiteralPath`, square brackets cause real problems with character escaping.  The problem comes from PowerShell de-escaping the strings multiple times internally and using special characters for pattern matching.  Getting PowerShell to correctly recognize a literal square bracket in a path string is complex.

If you're using single-quote strings, a bracket needs *two* backticks to escape it.  If you're using double-quote strings, a bracket needs *four* backticks to escape it.

If you're looking for a file named `MyFile[1].txt`, you need to use either:

```
'MyFile``[1``].txt'
```

or:

`````
"MyFile````[1````].txt"
`````

Yes, it's a pain.  To see why it does this, you have to know what's going on.  It's easy to do that by working backwards.

Let's say you want to get a file literally named `[ab].txt`.

The wildcard pattern matching that `Get-ChildItem` does means that if it gets `[ab].txt` as the path, then it will look for files named `a.txt`  and `b.txt`.  So, if we want to match a literal `[ab].txt`, we have to escape our brackets with the escape character: the backtick.  That gives us this as the actual string of characters we want `Get-ChildItem` to use for the filespec:

```
`[ab`].txt
```

However, we have to pass this filespec as a string.  That means `Get-ChildItem` will escape those backticks, but that's not what we want!  We want literal backticks.  So, we escape the backticks with backticks in our string to make sure `Get-ChildItem` uses the right filespec:

```
'``[ab``].txt'
```

If we want to use double-quoted strings, then we have to escape each backtick *again*, as the double-quoted string will de-escape the string.  And that's how you end up with this:

`````
"````[ab````].txt"
`````

This is why so many PowerShell functions that take filespecs have the `-LiteralPath` option.

Answer (score 8):

`RenameItem` doesn't have a `-LiteralPath` for <s>[some stupid reason](https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/12774.page)</s> (broken link).<sup>*</sup>

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath $i -destination $name
```

<sup>* <sub>Excuses from a co-designer of the language.</sub></sup>

`-LiteralPath` [appears](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.management.activities.renameitem.literalpath?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) to have been added.

Comment: Move-Item -LiteralPath $i -destination $name

throws this error: 

Rename-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LiteralPath'.

Comment: @TTrewitt: What version of PS?

Comment: The link in this answer has gone 404. Anyone know of a replacement?

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I fixed the link.

Comment: This answer introduced me to the `Literal-Path` parameter I needed to use for `Set-ACL -LiteralPath` that was interpreting `[]` in the filename as wildcards -- Thanks (Link doesn't work anymore sadly--even on archive.org :( )

Answer (score 3):

This finally achieved the desired result:

```
foreach ($i in get-childitem $folderpath) {
  if ($i.mode.substring(0,1) -ne “d”) {
    $name = $i.name.replace("[","_")
    $name = $name.replace("]","_")

   Write-Host $name -foregroundcolor “green”    
   [System.IO.File]::Move($folderPath+"\"+$i, $folderPath+"\"+$name) 
  }
}
```

Comment: -LiteralPath option does not work in Powershell version1 (Windows default version), if you are unable to upgrade to a newer Powershell due to workplace restrictions (Admin rights), this is by far the best solution to deal with the square brackets problem.