# Batch Move-Item operation only working on a fraction of the items

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch

I am trying to move all directories which contain a file named '√.txt' to a separate directory, with the following line of code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\music -Recurse -Filter √.txt | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique | 
Foreach-Object { Move-Item $_ -Destination D:\music\!listened -WhatIF }
```

...but it is only running the operation on maybe a tenth of the actual output. When I run only the first two pipeline operations, it will print to the console thousands of directories, but when I run the whole thing it will only show the operation being performed on maybe a few hundred.

If I run:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\music -Recurse -Filter √.txt | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique | 
Foreach-Object { Write-Output $_ }
```

...it will actually show every desired directory (in the thousands), but as soon as I change `Write-Output` to `Move-Item` it will only show the operation being performed on a small fraction, leaving out thousands of directories which contain the '√.txt' file.

What could be going wrong?

Edit: so the problem has to do with using square brackets [and here is a great link about it](https://superuser.com/questions/212808/powershell-bug-in-copy-move-rename-when-filename-contains-square-bracket-charac) provided to me in comments below.

Now I just need a one-liner to batch replace all `[]` with `()`!

Comment: Hello, which PowerShell version is it?  `-WhatIf` for `Write-Output` doesn't make a lot of sense BTW.

Comment: not sure which version, how to check? and yes I know I didn't need the WhatIF there; I forgot to remove it when replacing Move-Item. Also the issue turned out to be that the folders which wouldn't relocate had brackets in their titles... Now I need to figure out how to batch replace all the brackets in the folder names with parentheses...

Comment: As for how to check version, you could have googled that within the time it took you to ask for it, TBH.

Comment: thanks for the link and yes I should've googled (it's version 5.1.19041.3031). still not sure exactly how to solve my particular issue with -LiteralPath or something else... Should I make a new question and ask how to batch replace every instance of brackets in my subdirectory names?

Comment: If the above question had no answer that solved it for you, feel free to edit this one and accurately describe what fails now